# Remove "Column" Name / Attribute in SimpleDB

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-simpledb

I have a table (Domain) in AWS Simple DB and I would like to remove a single column from the "schema".

Was this possible to do somehow without recreating the whole table (Domain)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the command is called DeleteAttributes

From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_DeleteAttributes.html)

> Deletes one or more attributes associated with the item. If all
>   attributes of an item are deleted, the item is deleted.

I suppose you are doing this on many items, so you should probably look at BatchDeleteAttributes

From [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDB_API_BatchDeleteAttributes.html)

> Performs multiple DeleteAttributes operations in a single call, which
>   reduces round trips and latencies. This enables Amazon SimpleDB to 
>   optimize requests, which generally yields better throughput.

Hope it helps